# multidimenional class arrays from multidimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, debugging

I have a 9x9 array of values. I would like to divide those values up into 3x3 "Cells". These "Cells" are class objects that are also basically a 3x3 array. My problem is, when creating the loop, something doesn't happen correctly. I've added a line for debugging that puts out "Table[0,0].Item(0,0)", where "Table" is the 3x3 array of class objects and ".Item" is a function that returns what is at index .Item(x,y) in the "Cell". Unfortunately, for some reason this line for debugging puts out different values every time it loops. I have just gotten into coding, and I'm sure there's tons of better ways to solve this, but first I would like to figure out why my current code is not working to learn.

This is where I try and load the Table: ("table" with a lower case in the original 9x9 array)

```
static void Load_Table()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current cell: " + i + "/" + j);
                Cell tempCell = new Cell(table, i, j);
                Table[i, j] = tempCell;
                Console.WriteLine(Table[0, 0].Item(0, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

The Cell class:

```
    class Cell
{
    public static int[] Cellvalue = new int[2];
    public static int[,] content = new int[3, 3];
    private int[] contains = new int[9];
    public Cell(int[,] table,int column, int row)
    {
        Cellvalue[0] = column; Cellvalue[1] = row;

        for (int i = 0;i < 3; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}  {2}{3}",Cellvalue[0],Cellvalue[1],i,j);
                content[i, j] = table[i + (Cellvalue[0] * 3), j+ (Cellvalue[1] * 3)]; 
            } 
        }
    }
    public int Item(int column,int row)
    {
        return content[column, row];
    }

}
```

And table and Table:

```
    static public int[,] table = new int[9, 9];
    static public Cell[,] Table = new Cell[3, 3];
```

Thank you very much for the help in advance kind strangers <3.

Comment: Please, show us what happens inside `Cell` and `Table` classes. If initial array is 9x9, why your loops go till 3?

Comment: 9x9 with 3x3 cells? Is this a Sukdoku solver?

Comment: Thank you, just updated the post so that it includes the "Cell" class and it's construction.

@PavelAnikhouski it only loops 9 times, because when I create a "Cell" object, the contructor method in it also loops 9 times. Total of 81 loops.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, haha, that's what this is gonna be, but I don't yet really care about solving that problem, I'm just trying to see why this isn't working to learn for now.

Comment: Why do you need a static fields inside `Cell` class? like `public static int[] Cellvalue` and `public static int[,] content` Every `Cell` instance will share the same `content` and `Cellvalue`

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it! <3